# When to know it's time to fill the tyres with air again?

Tags: tires

A colleague says it is a best-practice to fill air in the car and bike tires once every two weeks. He says not doing so causes tiny wrinkles/cracks in the tubing and reduces the life of the tire faster.

Is this true? I tend to fill air in the tires only when I can feel that the air pressure is low (like when the vehicle moves over a road hump and I feel that the tire does not have enough air pressure).

What is recommended practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your driving style it may become obvious very rapidly when you need to add more pressure. If my front tyres drop by 2psi it dramatically affects high-G corners, so while I do pump them up every month at a minimum, if I feel cornering is not ideal I also go and check them as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

Fill them when they are low, but check them often. Once a week, or every fuel fill up. Car tires don't have tubes now a days, so you are actually sitting on the sidewall on the tire if they go flat.
Personally, I check every week as my tank last close to 3 weeks due to short commute.

Answer (score 2):

There are [gauges that mount to the valve stem in place of the cap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00084IBNQ). They show red when the pressure is low, green when it is correct. You can most likely get them locally at an auto supply/parts store or online. Once installed a quick glance will alert you to a low tire. In the U.S. they are available in different pressure ratings to match your vehicle specifications. After you have had them for awhile you can just check them every time you refuel.

[image: Valve stem cap tire pressure gauges]

Comment: These are really cool. In India though, it'd get stolen since it isn't common here.

Answer (score 0):

I check my car tires monthly.  At most they change a couple pounds either way (have to let a little air out in the Summer and have to add some in the Winter).  The amount that car tires leak seems to be pretty small compared to just the differences from temperature change.

Slightly OT, but since you asked...  I can get away with only checking my mountain bike tires only once a week, but the road bike I have to check it every day I ride it.  Skinny high pressure tires lose pressure FAST even just when sitting there!  :-)